routing a view through blueprint in another module doesn't work
I have a flask project with following three files:
# app.py

from flask import Flask

from userbp import bp

app =  Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world"

# userbp.py
from flask import Blueprint


bp = Blueprint("user", __name__, url_prefix="/user")

# user_views.py

from userbp import bp


@bp.route("/<string:name>")
def greet(name):
    return f"Hello, {name}! How are you?"

Here is the structure of this project's root directory:
.
├── __pycache__
│   ├── app.cpython-311.pyc
│   └── userbp.cpython-311.pyc
├── app.py
├── user_views.py
└── userbp.py

It is not working as expected, hitting the URL /John gives a 494 not found error. While if I move the greet view from user_views.py to userbp.py, it works as expected.
Why is it so?
How to fix this problem?
TYPO: It was actually 404 error
Thanks.

There a 2 solutions for this problem.

Best practices for blueprint in flask is that sub-route should define with same as blueprint initiations.

So your code should be like this
# app.py
from flask import Flask

# import blueprint from userbp.py
from userbp import bp

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(bp)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


# userbp.py

from flask import Blueprint

# initialization of blueprint
bp = Blueprint("user", __name__, url_prefix="/user")

## implementation of sub-route blueprints
@bp.route("/<string:name>")
def greet(name):
    return f"Hello, {name}! How are you?"


If you still want to separate initialization of blueprint and the implementation of sub-route you can do like this.

# app.py

from flask import Flask

# import blueprint from user_views.py
from user_views import bp

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(bp)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

# userbp.py

from flask import Blueprint


bp = Blueprint("user", __name__, url_prefix="/user")

# user_views.py

from userbp import bp


@bp.route("/<string:name>")
def greet(name):
    return f"Hello, {name}! How are you?"

So like this will work.
And the problem, why it's show error not found cause you accessing the wrong routes.
It Should be like this http://localhost:5000/user/john.
Cause in blueprint your code is defined to sub-route user
in here
bp = Blueprint("user", __name__, url_prefix="/user")


That's great! But can you please explain why? Especially the second approach. Is it like that the same blueprint object in two different modules are in different states? Is it flask specific, or is common to any python object in separate modules? Please clarify. Thanks...

I think I have confirmed. The two blueprint objects in two different modules are in two different states. importing the blueprint from userbp has the blueprint without the view functions routed, the blueprint object with routed view functions are in user_views module.
This is true with any other python object in two different, the same object can have two different states, if any one of the modules have done something with their imported instance.
